# Distilling questions

Tags: discussion, questions

It was discussed so many times, like [here](https://homebrew.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/162/ignoring-legality-is-homebrew-stack-exchange-going-to-encompass-distilling), but it seems the answer is always that it was decided like that in the begining.

Still, can it be changed today, to accept questions like [this](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/24380/how-to-brew-moonshine) one?

Answer (score 3):

I would have no objections to opening up the site to more distillation questions; as it is a post fermentation step :)

Answer (score 3):

To somewhat split the difference of the other answers, I think it could make a lot of sense to allow questions around *home* distilling.  If someone has a question more generally about distillation, particularly in a commercial setting, I think leaving that to https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/ seems reasonable.  But if someone has a question about distilling their fermented products themselves (i.e. at home) I think it could be reasonable to ask here, as long as they aren't specifically asking about how to break laws.

See my argument [here](https://homebrew.meta.stackexchange.com/a/454/12609) for why I personally think merging the two SE sites could also make sense.  But I think the same argument applies to Homebrewing just being a little more permissive instead of eschewing questions that, while about the creation (and/or modification) of alcoholic drinks at home, but aren't *technically* about homebrewing.  It seems like they're similar goals and would presumably appeal to many of the same users.

Answer (score 1):

I think these questions should be asked over at https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/ I think there is plenty of expertise on that stack. Let's keep it to homebrewing and wine

Comment: They indeed seem to talk about distilling over there.  But I think they talk more about the finished product in general?

Comment: I have the highest amount of points over there. I'm not that knowledgeable about booze as I am homebrew and especially wine but there are quite a few people that know the process. I would say more know the process there than in the Homebrew stack.

Comment: I would be happy for us to accept production questions over here and leave alcohol to deal with consumption questions. As it is often hard to discuss distillation without discussion of the fermentation of the wash.